# 編集サマリーの必要字数が 10 文字という規定

Tags: 機能の要求, 完了, 編集

編集サマリー（要約）について、文字数が 10 文字以上であることを要求されます。

この 10 文字という規定は本家 stackoverflow.com と同じですが、表意文字である漢字を使う日本語の字数の場合とかなり事情が異なり、しばしば悩むことがあります。

たとえば、stackoverflow.com では、編集サマリーのヒントとして、`improved formatting`（書式の改善）が示されており、私も時々、使用します。

表音文字のアルファベットによる記述なら、これでも 19 文字で、易々と規定字数に届きます。

ところが、ja.stackoverflow.com では、「書式の改善」と書くと、5 文字にしかならないわけです。

まるで、「書式の改善だけでの編集が許されない」かのようです（もちろん、実際はそうではありませんが）。

`corrected spelling`（誤字の修正）にしても同じことです。

せめて、5 文字程度にしてもらわないと、日本語ではバランスがとれないと思います。

現状では、無理に、他の修正項目を見つけて、複数項目を書き並べることで、どうにか 10 文字を達成していますが、本来、意図的に冗長な記述にするのは、プログラマー魂に逆らう（？）気もしないではないですし、また、要約（サマリー）が要約たる面目も損なわれる気もします。

できれば、文字数の調整をお願いしたいです。

Comment: 10文字→5文字を開発者に頼みます。

Comment: @jmac ありがとうございます。

Comment: @jmac 今確認すると8文字だったのですが、これが限界だったのでしょうか？

Comment: @unarist 設定ではまだ10みたいですので、開発者と再確認します。

Answer (score 2):

編集サマリーを最小5文字に設定しました。

もしバグ等を探した場合、ご教示ください。