# タイトルの文字数制限がバグっている（かも）？

Tags: バグ, 完了, タイトル

質問する際、短いタイトルを書こうとすると「タイトルは 8 文字以上でなければなりません。」というエラーが出ます。

[image]

このエラーメッセージにしたがってタイトルを 8 文字にすると、今度は「タイトルは少なくとも15文字必要です。」というエラーが出ます。

[image]

タイトルを 15 文字にすると、エラーは消えます。

[image]

つまり、なぜかエラーメッセージがふたつある状態になっています。また、過去に 8 文字以上 15 文字未満のタイトルの質問が投稿されたことがあります。これらのことから後者のエラーが出るのはバグなのではないかと疑っています。ローカリゼーションが上手くいってないのではないでしょうか。

#### 参考

- 例: 質問「[２次元配列は不連続か？](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/q/5022/19110)」のタイトルは 15 文字未満。

  - SEDE で調べました: https://data.stackexchange.com/ja/query/1102483/questions-with-title-15
- 関連質問？

  - [編集サマリーの必要字数が 10 文字という規定](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2001/19110)

    - これと同様の理由でタイトルの文字数制限が緩和されていたのに、どこかのタイミングで元に戻ってしまったのではないかとエスパーしています。

---

To Community Team

Title length limit may have a bug; its behavior was changed in July 2019 (according to @supa's comment). In SOja & SOja Meta, if we type a 6-character title, it says "Title must be at least 8 characters." Also, if we type a 8-character title, it shows "Title must be at least 15 characters." This seems strange. In fact, [we can post a question with |title| < 15](https://data.stackexchange.com/ja/query/1102483/questions-with-title-15) before July 2019. This behavior may be a localization bug, because in SOja [length limit of edit summary is different from other sites](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2001/19110).

Comment: もう少し文字数制限が戻ってしまった期間を絞ってみます。私が確認出来る中で最新の 15 文字以下の質問は、 2019-07-08 投稿の「[Pixi.jsのインポート](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/q/56495)」(13 文字) です。また、 2019-07-22 には、編集時にも[タイトルの文字数制限についてエラーが発生している](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2941#comment2815_2941)ことから、この 2 週間の間に何か変更があったのだと思います。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

修正が完了しました。

タイトルの最小の文字数は、元々はサイトの最小のコメント文字数である「8」から生成されていました。

数か月前にエンタープライズとチームのプロダクトに変更が加えられ、コメントとサイトに対する文字数の要件が個別に生成されました。これによってタイトルの文字数の要件を実行しながらサイトのコメントを短くすることが可能になりました。

このサイトの最小タイトル文字数は、最小コメント文字数「8」からデフォルトの最小タイトル文字数「15」に変更され、この時に残念ながらフロントエンド側ではなくバックエンド検証のみが更新されました。タイトルが8文字未満の場合、フロントエンドの検証ではコメントの最小文字数よりも短いと表示され、8〜14文字の場合にはバックエンド側から15未満と表示されました。

今回の修正箇所：

- 以前の動作に合わせてタイトルの最小文字数を「8」に設定しました。
- フロントエンドの検証が正しい値を反映するようにコードを更新しました。

---

This is fixed.

Minimum title length has historically been derived from the minimum comment length, which is 8 on this site.

A few months ago, a change was made for our Enterprise and Teams products to create separate length requirements for comments and sites.  This allows sites to have shorter comments while still enforcing a title length requirement.

When this happened, the minimum title length requirement for this site went from the minimum comment length of 8 to the default minimum title length of 15.  Unfortunately, only the backend validation was updated, not the frontend.  When a title was less than 8 characters, the frontend validation reported it as being shorter than the minimum comment length, and when it was between 8 and 14 characters, the backend reported it as being less than 15.

To fix this, I have:

- reduced the minimum title length to 8 to match the previous behavior,
- updated the code so that frontend validation reflects the correct value, should they ever differ.